# Returning an observable from another observable's .subscribe function

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscribe

I have a tiny observable problem in Angular with Typescript. The code below **doesn't** work, it's more for understanding what I want to do.

```js
getRefuels(): Observable<Refuel[]> {
    return new Observable<Refuel[]>((obs) => {
        this.hashService.getHashedUserEmail().subscribe((hashValue) => {

            //This is the observable I want to return
            return this.firestore
                .collection<Refuel>(`users/${hashValue}/refuels`, ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc'))
                .valueChanges({idField: 'id'});

        });
    });
}
```

I've tried to add a `.pipe(map(res => { return res; }))` but it didn't quite do what I wanted.
Also I've tried following code, but the data-types didn't fit:

```
obs.next(this.firestore
  .collection<Refuel>(`users/${hashValue}/refuels`, ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc'))
  .valueChanges({idField: 'id'}));

obs.complete();
```

It worked when I subscribed to my Firestore observable and then put the resulting list in the `obs.next()`, but this way I don't get list updates anymore.

Do you have an idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have 2 observables, you can use switchMap operator

```
first_observable.pipe(
  switchMap(result => {
   // do something with the result
   return second_observable;
   })
).subscribe(second_result => {
   // do something with result of second observable
});
```